# after a page reloads the box is still there i want to hide it once used

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i m a new to jquery and ajax plz some one can help here is my code.my problem is that when i search a area through a box which is taking its content from a database when i click on it it goes perfect but after reloading of page the box remains there i want to disappear it after a search

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready( function() {
             $('#searchpopup').click(function(){

                unloadPopupBox();
              });

                $('#change').click( function() {            
                loadPopupBox();
                });

            // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First


            $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {         
                unloadPopupBox();
            });

            $('#container').click( function() {
                unloadPopupBox();
            });

            function unloadPopupBox() { // TO Unload the Popupbox
                $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
                $("#container").css({ // this is just for style     
                    "opacity": "1"  
                });

            }   

            function loadPopupBox() {   // To Load the Popupbox
                $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
                $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                    "opacity": "0.3"  
                });         

            }
            /**********************************************************/

        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load_options('','country');
    });

    function load_options(id,index){
        $("#loading").show();
        if(index=="state"){
            $("#city").html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
            complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#"+index).html(data);
            }
        })

    }

    </script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                           new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                           new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                var center = null;
                var map = null;
                var currentPopup;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    bounds.extend(pt);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pt,
                        icon: icon,
                        map: map
                    });
                    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: info,
                        maxWidth: 300
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        if (currentPopup != null) {
                            currentPopup.close();
                            currentPopup = null;
                        }
                        popup.open(map, marker);
                        currentPopup = popup;
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                        map.panTo(center);
                        currentPopup = null;
                    });
                }           
                function initMap() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                        zoom: 14,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                        }
                    });


    <?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example where country_id='$country' and state_id='$state' and city_id='$city' ")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $lat = $row['lat'];
      $lon = $row['lon'];
      $desc = $row['desc'];



      echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

    }

    ?>
     center = bounds.getCenter();
         map.fitBounds(bounds);

         }
         </script>

    <body onLoad="initMap()">
    <div id="main-carrer">
         <div id="map"></div>
         <div id="popup_box">   <!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->
        <div style="width:241px; margin:auto;padding-top:40px;">

    <form action="map.php"  method="post">
    <table width="276" height="173" style="margin-left: -20px;margin-top: -28px;">
    <tr>

    <td width="105"><label>Select Region</label></td>
    <td width="155"><select  name="country" id="country" onChange="load_options(this.value,'state');">
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
        </select></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>   
        <td><label>Select Country</label></td>
        <td><select  name="state" id="state" onChange="load_options(this.value,'city');">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Select City</label></td>
        <td><select  name="city" id="city">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
            </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>      
      <td><input type="submit"  value="Search" id="searchpopup" style="margin-left:75px;"/></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
        <a id="popupBoxClose"><img src="images/cross2.png" style="width:22px; cursor:pointer;"></a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know which part to debug, really. Please reduce it to specific part.

Comment: only i want is the page do not reload after submit form and data can be fetched through database using its geolocation and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> only i want is the page do not reload after submit form and data can be fetched through database using its geolocation and stuff.

I understand that your ajax code works correctly, and the only problem is that, the form is submit too, to solve this problem,
disable your submit form by attaching a handler to it:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    // don't let the form to submit
    // and let ajax do its job
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: actually the thing is the fetching is done in a loop after selecting values from the form how i can i do it too in jquery or ajax so the page reload doesnt work and data can be fetched too.thanks